# When making an alias can quotation marks, apostrophes or semicolons prevent the command from working properly?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, syntax

I have a file called `.bash_aliases` where I keep my aliases.  While I have just one alias in the file it works properly, however when I try to create a new one the terminal fails to recognize the command line. Is the reason for this is a conflict between apostrophes `'` and quotation marks `"`?

**The alias:**

```
alias vid-dl="youtube-dl -o 'Videos/randon/%(title)s.%(ext)s'"
```

---

> **Error:** `vid-dl: command not found`

I used the aliases as follows in the terminal:

```
vid-dl URL
```

In `.bash_aliases`, is it necessary to use something to indicate that the line is finished? In other programming languages, like JavaScript and C#, lines are terminated by a semicolon (`;`).

When I tested the *command line* `youtube-dl -o 'Videos/randon/%(title)s.%(ext)s` without the alias it worked perfectly.

Comment: I added your alias to my Mint 19.2 system, and it was changed (automatically) to: `alias vid-dl='youtube-dl -o '\''Videos/randon/%(title)s.%(ext)s'\'''`.

Answer (score 0):

One uses backslash `\` to mark the following character as "unspecial", thus, from MY `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias bigopenfiles="sudo lsof / | awk '{if(\$7 > 1048576) print \$7/1048576 \"MB\" \" \" \$9 }' | sort -n -u" 
# 
alias deletedfiles="sudo lsof / | egrep 'PID|\(deleted\)'"
#
```

Let's take the complicated expression apart:

```
alias bigopenfiles="sudo lsof / | awk '{if(\$7 > 1048576) print \$7/1048576 \"MB\" \" \" \$9 }' | sort -n -u"
```

is surrounded by `"`s, so any character that would confuse the parsing code must be baskslash-escaped.

The `'`s surrounding the `awk` program are not of interest to the parsing code (it's looking for a matching `"`).

However, the dollar signs are special (could mean 7th parameter of the shell where you're defining the alias, a silly idea), and must be backslash-escaped, e.g. `\$7`.

Then there's the count-on-fingers `\"MB\" \" \"`, two quoted strings for `awk`, with all quote marks backslash-escaped.

The `'`s surrounding the `awk` program are not of interest to the parsing code (it's looking for a matching `"`).

finally, there are the other commands in the alias (this time it's just `| sort -n -u`, and,

finally,

the close quote (`"`) NOT backslash-escaped.

The next time the string is parsed, the backslashes vanish:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ alias bigopenfiles
alias bigopenfiles='sudo lsof / | awk '\''{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }'\'' | sort -n -u'
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the current terminal and open a new terminal window for the `.bash_aliases` file to take effect.

Or, simply `. ~/.bash_aliases`.